# Mathematica Community Polls

Tags: discussion

This thread is used for opinion and usage polls around [Wolfram *Mathematica*](http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/). The poll questions are added as *answers* to this question. The choices for each specific poll can be found as comments below them. To participate simply up-vote the comments which apply for you. If there is no suitable answer yet simply add it as comment by yourself.
You can't up-vote your own comments but the comment author will be counted manually. Please do not add any other comments to these posts. General comments can be added under this *question*.

#### Rules

- Feel free to add your own poll by creating a new *answer post* below.
- Answers to these poll questions are placed as *comments* below them. Because this is also an opinion poll subjective questions are welcome.
- To participate up-vote the comments which apply for you.
- If required add a new answer as a comment.

  <sub>If applicable hyperlink the entry to allow other users to learn more     about it. Feel free to flag comments for moderator attention if they should be modified for some valid reason (wrong/missing hyperlink, etc.)</sub>
- Feel free to up-vote the poll questions (*answer* posts) as well to indicate that you liked the question. This will push the most favorite questions to the top.
- Do not post any other answer posts or comments.

Answer (score 18):

If you are active in this community, it may be presumed you love *Mathematica*. But even so there are bound to be some features that irritate you. What are they?

If you don't see something that irritates you on the list, please feel free to add it.

Comment: The front end's so-called undo feature

Comment: Missing or incomplete documentation for certain features, e.g. `Method` options

Comment: No auto-completion for options when they are strings.

Comment: Long lasting bugs.

Comment: The occasional surge in memory usage leading to a fully crippled system.

Comment: User-unfriendly way to specify `Ticks` and `FrameTicks`.

Comment: There are too many options with unintuitive default values.

Comment: The inabilty to shut a calculation down reliably. Abort evaluation just does not do the job.

Comment: That pressing `Ctrl+S` in a notebook with large output (e.g. videos, lots of images) will hang for several minutes, than crash, and I'll have lost both my unsaved work *and* the previously saved version. Couldn't MMA save the output cells to a separate file? Or at least back up the original file before overwriting it?

Comment: It irritates me that pressing CTRL-C with nothing selected erases the clipboard. (Windows Mathematica 10.0.2).

Answer (score 16):

The *Mathematica* way of distributing code are [notebooks](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/NotebooksAsDocuments.html) and [packages](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/MathematicaPackages.html). While notebooks are often used for everyday work, prototyping and testing, packages are more for distributing/storing functions so that they can easily be loaded for later use. How often do you write packages?

Comment: I never wrote a package by myself. I only use notebooks for my work.

Comment: I have written a package once or twice, but in general I stick to notebooks.

Comment: I write packages regularly.

Comment: 1 package that I use everyday.

Answer (score 14):

Do you use any other editor or [IDE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment) other than the *Mathematica* front end to write code, especially for package development?

Comment: I always use the *Mathematica* front end.

Comment: I use the [Wolfram *Workbench*](http://www.wolfram.com/products/workbench/) for package development.

Comment: I use the [*Mathematica* plugin for IntelliJ IDEA](http://www.halirutan.de/start) for package development.

Comment: I mostly use the _Mathematica_ front end, but I occasionally sneak into a text-based code editor to do editing  -- such as regex search and replace -- that is hard or impossible to do in the front end.

Comment: I use the [Wolfram Workbench as a plug-in to a later version of Eclipse](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18183/8) .

Comment: I use a plain text editor (not a project-based IDE), such as Vim, SublimeText, Notepad++ etc.

Comment: I use Wolfram Workbench only for package testing.

Answer (score 13):

Today, *Mathematica* is available for the three big operating systems: Windows, Mac OS X and Linux. On which operating system do you use *Mathematica*?

Comment: I use Windows as operating system.

Comment: I use Mac OS X as operating system.

Comment: I use Linux as operating system.

Answer (score 11):

In what setting do you primarily use *Mathematica*?

Comment: As a researcher in academia.

Comment: For a job outside academia.

Comment: As a university student.

Comment: At home as a hobby.

Answer (score 10):

How would you describe Mathematica usage in your working environment?

Comment: We have a site license and everybody is using it

Comment: I am the only user and I have to fight to prolong my Premier Service License

Comment: A couple of guys are using it, but it's mostly Matlab/Python/C++ etc.

Comment: Nobody is using it, except for me and I have a home use license.

Comment: A few people are using it now, but usage is growing across different areas.

Comment: If one would mention Mathematica to my coworkers, their response would be "Mathe-WHAT??"

Comment: We have a site license but I'm the only one whose job is based on working with MMA.

Comment: I am the only one developing in Mathematica, but there a several users of the resulting CDF files.

Answer (score 10):

What do you use Mathematica mostly for?

Comment: As a calculator.

Comment: High performance computing.

Comment: Symbolic math .

Comment: Image Processing & Analysis.

Comment: Data processing & visualisation.

Comment: Applications/games/GUIs, usually related to CDF format.

Comment: Monte Carlo simulation

Comment: Algorithm development & Prototyping

Comment: Visualizing various interesting geometrical structures and relationships

Comment: Modeling the behavior of living organisms (biological simulation)

Comment: Engineering R&D

Comment: graphics and graphic design

Answer (score 9):

Have you ever modified a Wolfram Research provided style sheet or written your own front end style sheet.

Comment: I have modified a Wolfram Research provided style sheet

Comment: I have written my own style sheet

Comment: I have neither modified nor written a style sheet

Comment: I have modified the provided style sheets but only for very small changes like ShowGroupOpener->True